# Unity Movement, Program cancels horizontal momentum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So my script for movement in unity sets horizontal momentum and then cancels it out. However I wish to make a walljumping mechanic, which doesn't work properly when the horizontal momentum is set. I can't figure out a way around this and really need help. (unity2d)

Comment: People can not help you, if you don't provide the relevant code. See more regarding this at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you could edit the post to show all scripts that involve horizontal movement, or double check those scripts to see if horizontal movement is reset/turned off by any update methods. More information would help to solve your issue.